# How to group together values in Python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

I am having trouble creating a count of screen_size values above 6 inches for each brand_name.

The data:

[image]

My code thus far:

df.loc[df["screen_size"]>=6.0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.loc[df["screen_size"]>=6.0,"brand_name"].value_counts()
```

(i) `df.loc[df["screen_size"]>=6.0,"brand_name"]` is a pandas Series that consists of the rows of the `brand_name` column where the corresponding `screen_size>=6`

(ii) `value_counts()` method counts each `brand_name` in that pandas Series.

Answer (score 0):

No need for loc

```
df2 = df[df["screen_size"]>=6.0]
print(df2.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
print((df.loc["screen_size"]>=6.0).count())
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use loc,Maybe try:

```
df.loc[:,df["screen_size"]>=6.0]
```